# Can I add a day to control-m based on the current system time?

Tags: control-m

I am currently working on sending rundate and time in the PostData via a control-m job.

I want to add a day to current date when time is before noon. But if the time is pass 12, then keep the rundate as is. Is that possible

I am able to add a day to rundate and send it. But not able to implement the condition like if else when the date is before and after noon